# Find the coefficients of a polynomial given its roots (zeros) in Prolog

Tags: math, prolog, logic, polynomial-math

How I can implement in Prolog program that find coefficients of the polynomial if I know its roots.

for example:

```
input data (2;-1)
output (1;-1;2)
```

Comment: multiply out an example, eq (x-x1)(x-x2)(x-x3)(x-x4). the pattern should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Have you given any thought to *representing* polynomials in Prolog? In your example, it appears the coefficients of a polynomial are separated by semicolons inside a pair of parentheses.  Printing the output this way is easily done, provided these same coefficients are represented as a list.

Comment: The `output` shown is incorrect since (x-2)(x+1) = x^2 - x - 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiplying together the first-degree factors for given roots will form an expanded polynomial.  This is a natural fit with an "accumulator" design pattern in Prolog.

That is, we'll introduce an auxiliary argument to remember the product of factors "so far" dealt with.  Once the list of specified roots has been emptied, then we will have the desired polynomial expansion:

```
/* polynomialFromListofRoots(ListofRoots,[1],Polynomial) */
polynomialFromListofRoots([ ],Poly,Poly).
polynomialFromListofRoots([R|Roots],Pnow,Poly) :-
    polyMultiplyRootFactor(R,Pnow,Pnew),
    polynomialFromListofRoots(Roots,Pnew,Poly).

/* polyMultiplyRootFactor(R,Poly,ProductXminusR) */
polyMultiplyRootFactor(R,Poly,Prod) :-
    polyMultiplyRootFactorAux(R,0,Poly,Prod).

/* polyMultiplyRootFactorAux(R,Aux,Poly,Product) */
polyMultiplyRootFactorAux(R,A,[ ],[B]) :-
    B is -R*A.
polyMultiplyRootFactorAux(R,A,[P|Ps],[RP|RPs]) :-
    RP is P - R*A,
    polyMultiplyRootFactorAux(R,P,Ps,RPs).
```

Using the example in the Question:

```
?- polynomialFromListofRoots([2,-1],[1],Poly).

Poly = [1, -1, -2]
yes
```

Note that this corrects the `output` claimed in the Question.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry misread question.

a^2x + bx +c = 0

Take the sum of the roots x1 + x2 this is equal to -b/a.

Take the product of the roots x1*x2 this is equal to c/a.

Now solve the resulting system of linear equations to find a b and c.

Edit:

The above solution works if you set the parameter of a = 1. You see when your given the roots you'll end up with two equations and three unknowns so you'll have to set a fixed value on one of the parameters and the above solutions fixes a = 1.

So given 2 roots you can't get back a specific polynomial because theres no unique answer theres an infinte number of answers

Comment: (2;-1) => f(x) = (x-2)*(x+1) = x^2 - x - 2 => (1;-1;-2)

Comment: Well it depends do you only want your equation to be in the form x^2 + bx + c (ie are you happy to set a = 1)

Comment: but I can have more than two roots

Comment: I don't think its that easy to solve because a polynomial f(x) has specific roots. But roots don't have a specific polynomial so if your given a number of roots there an infinite number of polynomials that satisfy these roots. So your program would only be able to give out one of these and to decide what to set each parameter to could be very difficult to determine. Was this given as homework does it specify what the program must do?

Comment: the result is unique within a multiplier, assuming you have all the roots.